# Divide Footer into textbox and small button, Cordova Android App

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, cordova

I'm designing a page containing footer which contains long text box depending on the mobile device and a button adjacent to it, which will remain fix without considering the mobile device.

Following is the code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"
            data-theme="e" style="position: fixed;" class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
            <input type="text" id="addComment" name="addComment" data-inline="true"></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="#" data-rel="popup"  class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" style="float:right;"></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Can we manipulate the **ui-block-a** width, to capture 80% of the width and remaining 20% only for the button??
 Or is there some other possibility?

I want to make the appearance of the footer resembling as it is instagram while viewing comments or adding comments.

Comment: You can try make an inline style for the `<div class="ui-block-a">` element. e.g `<div class="ui-block-a"  style="width: 80%;">`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried out that its not working.

Comment: you can have a look over here. link [setting width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334269/jquery-mobile-set-width-of-2-elements-to-80-and-20)

Comment: ihave tried out this but if you take <textarea> instead of <input>
the send button will not be in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="width:80% !important">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83y2L/)